# Могу ли я дать Тэг(никнейм) структуре такие как "struct" или "typedef"?

Tags: c

То есть если я обозначаю структуру, могу ли я дать такие никнеймы данной структуре? Например

```
struct typedef
{
    int width;
    int length;
}
```

или

```
struct struct
{
    int width;
    int length;
}
```

Почему спрашиваю мне попался такой вопрос при Тесте
[image: Сам вопрос]

Comment: если что, вопрос из теста: «С помощью какого ключевого слова можно присвоить структуре псевдоним?»

Comment: Я думаю вы всётаки неправильно перевели вопрос. Поэтому при такой формулировке которая получилась у вас - ответы не подходят.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос был: какое ключевое слово **может создать псевдоним** для типа данных структуры?

Ответ - **typedef**. Например так :

```
typedef
  struct structname
nickname ;
```

или

```
typedef
  struct structname {
    поля ...
  }
nickname ;
```

Вы неправильно поняли вопрос и задаёте **имя структуре** ключевым словом языка. А такое нельзя делать.

> ```
> struct struct
> {
>     int width;
>     int length;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Нельзя делать так, как вы *хотите*. Слова из набора:

```
auto    else    long    switch
break   enum    register    typedef
case    extern  return  union
char    float   short   unsigned
const   for     signed  void
continue    goto    sizeof  volatile
default     if  static  while
do  int     struct  _Packed
double
```

являются служебными и не могут быть использованы не по прямому назначению.